# Steam - Dx11 Feature Level 10.0 Is Required to Run the Engine Error linux

Tags: steam

I know it is an issue with old graphic cards. Is there are work around? Please see screenshots for my machine specs and the error message I get when I launch the game in my Steam library. I tried various Proton builds from the newest to less recent ones.

Five Nights at Freddy's: Security Breach is the game I'd like to play.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm also getting this issue, but only with the latest proton (8.0) and an nvidia GTX 1080